# CSS cursor image bizarre issue

Tags: html, css, cursor

Am I missing something very obvious here? I'm trying to replace the cursor css property with a png as demonstrated [here](https://css-tricks.com/using-css-cursors/)

I have it working with the demo 'happy.png' but can't understand why its not working with my 'call-me-hand.png'

```
.next {
   cursor: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/9632/happy.png"), auto;
   cursor: url("https://robcleaton.github.io/warface/assets/images/call-me-hand.png"), auto;
}
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/cleaton/pen/gOwLEyg)

Comment: only one property is allowed, you are overriding the first with the second

Comment: Thanks, I added two for demonstration purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cursor property has limits on the url value based on Browsers and OS. For example, Images larger than 128 x 128 Pixels aren't supported on Firefox. To make it work, reduce the dimensions of the given image.

Further information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Basic_User_Interface/Using_URL_values_for_the_cursor_property

Comment: Thank you!! This is where I was going wrong

Answer (score 0):

I tried your pen using [this link](https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/apple/271/call-me-hand_1f919.png) and... it worked! Not sure why it doesn't with yours though...

Comment: To clarify, the happy.png is working it's the call-hand that isnt